# Dual boot ubuntu and windows 10, multiple restarts required after grub page

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, login-screen

I have a dual boot config Ubuntu 16.04 + Windows 10 on two separate SSDs. After grub page shows up, I can either boot windows or Ubuntu. Windows 10 always boots fine. However, Ubuntu gets to login page and after I enter my password it shows a blank screen. Only after multiple restarts and shutdowns I can login to the Ubuntu which surprises me even more. More strangely, it has been like this for more than 10 months and every time I need to do something in windows I have to restart the computer multiple times to get back to Ubuntu.

I have a feeling it is a graphics card issue. I have a GTX 780 and I have installed the latest Nvidia driver from their website but I have had the same issue with the older drivers too. I have tried many routes but I have not seen many people having this same issue. Let me know if you have had the same issue and have a work around.